# Rails - How to pass a local variable to partial in a shared folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I'm trying to get comments to show up in a blog post. Comments are associated with the posts. But I can't figure out how to pass the `@post.comments` to a partial file in a shared folder.

Here's the error:

```
undefined method `body' for #<Comment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:>
```

Here's the partial call in the `show.html.erb` file:

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/comment', locals: { comment: @post.comments } %>
```

Here's the `_comment.html.erb` partial:

```
<%= comment.name %>
<%= comment.body %>
<%= comment.created_at %>
```

Comment model migration:

```
create_table :comments do |t|
  t.string :name
  t.text :body
  t.references :post, index: true, foreign_key: true
```

But the model isn't the problem because I can get it to work with a simple `<%= render @post.comments %>` and placing the `_comment.html.erb` partial in the /views/comments/ folder. However, I want to keep all the partials in the /shared folder (and learn why that even works in the first place).

I've spent hours looking for a solution here and reading [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html) over and over. Tried every variation possible. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code.

```
<%= render partial: 'shared/comment', collection: @post.comments, as: :comment %>
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess it's because I'm trying to render a collection, instead of just a single variable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you're trying to render is a collection but you treated it as a single object, try to iterate through them and render each item.

By the way using a REPL to pause the execution of program and inspect the variable might enormously help you debug these kind of problems.

You can inspect global and local variables even run your custom code and see the result.

[Pry](http://www.alanmacdougall.com/blog/2012/06/08/interactive-debugging-with-pry/) is the de-facto standard atm.